# How to make dynamic pivot table based on Stored Procedure Parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pivot-table

How I can make stored procedure display dynamic pivot columns? the current query can only display fix number of columns. For example :

```
call ABC('malaysia,japan,pakistan');
```

Above stored procedure call is working fine. It shows this result

```
| Malaysia   |  Pakistan  |  Japan   |
  16:53:11     13:53:11     17:53:11
```

and when i call the stored procedure ABC with 2 countries it will show 3 columns  too with null value for the country not in passing String . Like this :

```
 call ABC('malaysia,pakistan');
```

it will show this result :

```
| Malaysia   |  Pakistan  |  Japan  |
  16:53:11      13:53:11     null
```

What I want is, to make the stored procedure show  only pivot columns which is only being called by the stored procedure ABC. It should be like this one if I use this :

```
call ABC('malaysia,pakistan');
```

I want the result to be this :

```
| Malaysia   |  Pakistan  |
  16:53:11      13:53:11
```

Below is full code of the stored procedure. Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ABC`(fullstr varchar(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
  DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
DELETE FROM country2;
  SET  @num := 0;
  simple_loop: LOOP
     SET a=a+1;
     SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a);
     IF str='' THEN
        LEAVE simple_loop;
     END IF;
     #Inserts into temp table here with str going into the row
     insert into country2(countryname) values (str);
END LOOP simple_loop;

UPDATE country2 
SET countryid = @num:=(@num + 1);
ALTER TABLE country2 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;

SELECT 
MAX(IF(country2.countryname = 'malaysia',
    ADDTIME(TIME(UTC_TIMESTAMP()), country.UTC),
    NULL)) AS 'malaysia',
MAX(IF(country2.countryname = 'pakistan',
    ADDTIME(TIME(UTC_TIMESTAMP()), country.UTC),
    NULL)) AS 'pakistan',
MAX(IF(country2.countryname = 'japan',
    ADDTIME(TIME(UTC_TIMESTAMP()), country.UTC),
    NULL)) AS 'japan'
FROM
country
    JOIN
country2 ON country.countryname = country2.countryname;
END
```

**NOTES--ONLY TABLE country has UTC data. while TABLE country2 only a TEMP table to store the country name(from stored procedure parameter).

Answer (score 0):

The full code for "dynamic" pivoting is found in [my pivot blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot).  It is a stored procedure that first discovers the column names desired, then constructs the `SELECT` statement and executes it.

This might get you what you want:

```
CALL Pivot('country', '', 'countryname', 'UTC', '', '');
```

Actually, it probably needs a minor tweak (as discussed in the blog) to get rid of `SUM`, which you don't seem to need.

Comment: I didnt get it. So what actually I have to change in my code?

Comment: Remove "SUM" from the code (leaving the rest of the statement); Install the modified Stored Procedure; `CALL` it (as shown in the 'Answer').  I hope (but can't say for sure) that it will (1) present a SELECT statement that does the task you desire, and (2)execute that SELECT to produce the results that you desire.  If it fails it might at least be close to what you want.  You might then choose to abandon the Stored Procedure, and simply keep the SELECT.